# ngFormio Renderer - Wizard Titles Overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[image: click here for image]

is there a way to show the wizard step titles on the left side and the rendered elements on the right side?
I have form step titles that are long and they overlap, making the rendered form look ugly.

i don't want to hack around to move the step titles to the left if there is an option that does it in a cleaner way.

**EDIT**

[expected layout](https://www.google.com/search?q=turbotax&rlz=1C1GCEA_en___US751&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuwbLPkoLXAhUCwiYKHTcyA3QQ_AUIDSgE&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=zViSPFcpxVbMGM:)

ngFormio Codepen Example.
pick wizard from select to create a wizard form

```
'https://codepen.io/travist/embed/xVyMjo?height=600&theme-id=0&slug-hash=xVyMjo&default-tab=result&user=travist&embed-version=2&pen-title=Form.io%20Form%20Building%20and%20Rendering)'
```

Thanks

Comment: please make a demo how you want it

Comment: see above edit. thanks